# How to get the first level of data in JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an external JSON file called `movie.json` and it is like the following format:

```
{
    "action":
        [
            { "id": "1001", "name": "Matrix" },
            { "id": "1002", "name": "IP Man" },
            { "id": "1003", "name": "Revenge" }
        ],
    "comedy":
        [
            { "id": "2001", "type": "Iceman" },
            { "id": "2002", "type": "Pat & Mat" },
            { "id": "2003", "type": "Sugar" }
        ],
    "animation":
        [
            { "id": "3001", "type": "Frozen" },
            { "id": "3002", "type": "Tangled" },
            { "id": "3003", "type": "Croods" }
        ]
}
```

In my HTML I have a bootstrap Tab component like

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
</ul>
```

How can I get access to upper level of JSON file (`action, comedy, animation` and populate them as `li` in `.nav-tabs` dynamically?

I already tried:

```
 $.getJSON('data.json', function (data) {
       for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
             $('.nav-tabs').append('<li role="presentation" ><a href="#'+data[0]+'" aria-controls="'+data[0]+'" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">'+data[0]+'</a></li>')
   }
  });
```

but it is not doing the job.

Comment: file name is incorrect replace data.json to movie.json

Comment: use `Object.keys(data)` in order to get an array like `['action', 'comedy', 'animation']`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$.each()` to iterate the data. key will be the "top level" and val the content

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function (data) {
   $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
     $('.nav-tabs').append('<li role="presentation" ><a href="#'+key+'" aria-controls="'+key+'" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">'+key+'</a></li>')
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet SunriseM, but Can you also let me know how I can publish the values in second level? I mean if I have table on each `.tab-content` of bootstrap , how can I export them to the tabels? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You treating object like an array, its a simple object Use [`for-in` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

> The `for...in` statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an object, in arbitrary order. For each distinct property, statements can be executed.

```js
var data = {
  "action": [{
      "id": "1001",
      "name": "Matrix"
    },
    {
      "id": "1002",
      "name": "IP Man"
    },
    {
      "id": "1003",
      "name": "Revenge"
    }
  ],
  "comedy": [{
      "id": "2001",
      "name": "Iceman"
    },
    {
      "id": "2002",
      "name": "Pat & Mat"
    },
    {
      "id": "2003",
      "name": "Sugar"
    }
  ],
  "animation": [{
      "id": "3001",
      "name": "Frozen"
    },
    {
      "id": "3002",
      "name": "Tangled"
    },
    {
      "id": "3003",
      "name": "Croods"
    }
  ]
};

for (var i in data) {
  $('.nav-tabs').append('<li><strong>' + i + '<strong></li>')
  for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
    var obj = data[i][j];
    $('.nav-tabs').append('<li>' + obj.name + '</li>')
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// jsonObj is your json object
jQuery.each(jsonObj, function(key,val) {
//key will have action,comedy and animation
console.log(key,val)
});
```